# Java 3D-API that uses JOGL

Tags: java, 3d, jogl

Can someone recommend me a package similar to JCollada for 3d rendering that is based on JOGL or point me to a place where I can obtain JCollada?  The original site for JCollada has a SVN link that is no longer working (empty svn repositry).

Answer (score 3):

I think jMonkeyEngine 3 is the right library for you. jME3 can use either LWJGL or JOGL for rendering.

Here's the link: 
http://code.google.com/p/jmonkeyengine/

Have fun!

Comment: From the jMonkeyEngine website: "OpenGL is supported via LWJGL, with JOGL support in development."

Comment: The new release has JOGL support.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you can try Jzy3d which provides lot of easy to use 3d primitives and tools.

Cheers,

Martin

http://code.google.com/p/jzy3d